# What is the difference between (while queue) and (while not queue.empty()) in Python3

Tags: python, while-loop, queue

I found the difference between
`while queue` and `while not queue.empty()` in `python3`

I thought these are the same, but it wasn't.

when I used

> While queue :
> -> after I used all items in the queue, It just stopped. (No errors)

On the other hand, when I used

> While not (queue.empty()):
> -> it worked as what I thought.

Is there any difference? Or there was something I did wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`while queue:` will keep looping forever since it's only checking that `queue` object isn't `None`. It doesn't care whether it's empty or not, just that the object exists.

For example:

```
from queue import SimpleQueue

q = SimpleQueue()

while q:
    print ("Queue empty? ", q.empty())
```

The above script will print "Queue empty? True" infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like:

```python
from queue import Queue

q = Queue(maxsize = <maxsize as per your concern>)

while not q.empty():
   print("Queue empty: ", q.empty())
   q.get() #to avoid infinite loop
```

As per your question, the same followed for me and this was the way I cleared it out so clearly they both are different.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide an explanation to your code so that it would useful in future too.

Comment: Yeah! basically I thought It would be self explainatory but I'll keep it in mind from now.